# Most used Numbers in Lottery Database

Tags: database

I have an Access 2000 database that contains a table of little lotto numbers.  The first column is "Drawdate", the second "P1", the third "P2", the fourth "P3", the fifth "P4", and the sixth "P5".  I'm trying to find 10 numbers from the table that are used the most together.

10 numbers used 5 at a time would produce 252 combinations. From the table of winning numbers I want to find 10 numbers most used in groups of 5.

Comment: Would you elaborate on "used the most together"?

Comment: Access isn't a database.

Comment: 10 numbers used 5 at a time would produce 252 combinations.  From the table of winning numbers I want to find 10 numbers most used in groups of 5.

Comment: DRAWDATE P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
11/14/2009 01 19 30 35 39
11/15/2009 01 10 27 32 33
11/16/2009 03 07 15 23 29
11/17/2009 06 11 15 18 30
11/18/2009 04 07 12 15 21
11/19/2009 06 15 18 30 35
11/20/2009 01 19 20 27 34
11/21/2009 01 03 12 19 33
11/22/2009 11 15 18 30 35
11/23/2009 01 06 14 26 37
In this table, eventhough 01 is most used number, 06,11,15,18,30,35 are the 6 most used together numbers since the have 3 winning combinations. In a larger table I want to be able to find 10 most used together numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I would unpivot the data first so you have:

```
DrawDate, Position, Number
```

Where Position in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Since you don't care really about position, it's easy enough to exclude it from queries now (or drop the column altogether).

The portable UNPIVOT is:

```
SELECT DrawDate, 1 AS Position, P1 AS [Number] FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT DrawDate, 2 AS Position, P2 AS [Number] FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT DrawDate, 3 AS Position, P3 AS [Number] FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT DrawDate, 4 AS Position, P4 AS [Number] FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT DrawDate, 5 AS Position, P5 AS [Number] FROM tbl
```

This can actually be embedded to find a most used number result without remodelling your data (I'm not even bothering with the DrawDate and Position):

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Number], COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT /* DrawDate, 1 AS Position, */ P1 AS [Number] FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT /* DrawDate, 2 AS Position, */ P2 AS [Number] FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT /* DrawDate, 3 AS Position, */ P3 AS [Number] FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT /* DrawDate, 4 AS Position, */ P4 AS [Number] FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT /* DrawDate, 5 AS Position, */ P5 AS [Number] FROM tbl
) AS unpivoted
GROUP BY [Number]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you define what you mean by numbers used together...

Comment: Sample Table
DRAWDATE P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 
11/14/2009     01 19 30 35 39 
11/15/2009     01 10 27 32 33 
11/16/2009     03 07 15 23 29 
11/17/2009     06 11 15 18 30 
11/18/2009     04 07 12 15 21 
11/19/2009     06 15 18 30 35 
11/20/2009     01 19 20 27 34 
11/21/2009     01 03 12 19 33 
11/22/2009     11 15 18 30 35 
11/23/2009     01 06 14 26 37 
In table, even though 01 is most used #, 06,11,15,18,30,35 are the 6 most used together #s since they have 3 winning combinations.I have table containing winning #s (1–39) from a 5 # lotto.I need a set of 10 #s used in 5 # combinations with most wins

Answer (score 0):

You need to count how many times each number is used.

But you do not know which column a number could be in.

Therefore your could first count how many times the number 1 appears in all columns, then the number 2 and so on.

```
SELECT Count(*) WHERE P1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd build a second table from the first. Something like...

`INSERT INTO tblNumbers(Number,NumCount) SELECT P1, count(P1) from tblDraws group by P1
INSERT INTO tblNumbers(Number,NumCount) SELECT P2, count(P2) from tblDraws group by P2
INSERT INTO tblNumbers(Number,NumCount) SELECT P3, count(P3) from tblDraws group by P3
etc`

then at the end, just execute

`SELECT Number Number, SUM(NumCount) from tblNumbers group by Number`